# modify the title of an action in ng2 smart table or add a new one

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I want to add a new action to ng2-smart-table or to modify the title of (add, edit or delete). I tried to add the ButtonView but i can't reproduce any action with it.

Can any one help me please ?

Comment: can you bind the title to a var in your component file and modify that?

Comment: @Surreal first of all thank you for the fast reply. I tried to change it like this `add: { title: 'Something', confirmCreate: true, }` in the setting of the data-table.

Comment: i **SOLVED IT** by changing like this `add: { addButtonContent: 'Affecter', confirmCreate: true, }`
Thank you very much for your time and i hope it will help other people looking for the answer

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change the title of the actions column:

```
settings = {
   actions: { columnTitle: 'something'},
   ...
}
```